# help: when update the substrate 4.0 custom type json file

Tags: custom-types

I haven't found the custom type JSON file on GitHub,  where can I download it

> 

Comment: Welcome to the community 

Comment: Please take some time to review https://substrate.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask to learn how to form better questions. As it is this question is too broad. What chain? What's the purpose to update? Etc.

Answer (score 4):

With the current master Substrate versions (and all chains that are recent **), there is no need for specific type injections, nor are there any specific external type bundles.

Since metadata v14 was introduced, the metadata itself exposes all the specific type definitions. this means that when any API queries the metadata, it retrieves the full information of all the call interfaces as well as a full specification of the types used in those interfaces.

** Most chains have now adopted Metadata v14, this includes most of the parachains, the relay chains, etc.

Comment: Yup! More details here https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/pull/8615